# Unable to find ASP.NET Web Service in file

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I am trying to develop a web service application. I am following this [website](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_web_services.htm) to develop the web service, as from the instructions when I open the VS2013 and Select File -> New -> Web Site in Visual Studio, I did not found this Asp.net web service. I got as below image.

[image]

Do I have to install any templates?

I have also tried to Installed the web service template by online but when I click on it and searched I got nothing, like my below image.

[image]

Can someone help me to do it.

Note: I am connected to Internet.

Comment: try using new features like ASP.NET Web API 2 http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

Comment: So, you didn't get far through that tutorial then !  You could try my tutorial, which is friendlier, and walks you through the entire process, all the way through consuming its data from iOS or Angular:  http://mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/Services/WebServices-Page1.htm

Answer (score 0):

please follow below steps:

- Right Click on Project/Application
- Select Add new Item
- Select Installed Tab
- Select Visual Basic or Visual C#
- Find Web Service (ASMX)

Comment: *I think* he wants to create a service not use an existing one.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what kind of web service you want to create really.

In your example you're using the "New Web Site" dialog.

More modern web services (Web API etc) instead use "New Project" dialog. Open that and choose "ASP.NET Web Application" and you can choose what you want from the subsequent dialog.

See here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got it, I have the change the .Net framework from 4.5 to .Net framework 3.5.

[image]
Thanks for your time and your help :)